# Two same words in string

Tags: php

I have problem and I dont have any idea how solve it.
I have strings for example this.

```
$string = "car apple computer car"
$string2 = "car apple computer"
```

I need function, which can to distinguish if string contain two same words. So for $string return 1 and for $string2 return 0

Comment: Can you show what you have so far?

Comment: Use `explode` and associative arrays.. shouldn't be the hardest task to iterate over the words and insert them into an array

Comment: `return array_unique(explode(' ', $string)) == explode(' ', $string);`

Comment: @NigelRen How i wrote in question... I dont have any idea how solve it..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `explode` to convert the string into an array. Use `array_unique` to get the unique words. If the count of unique words and the count of the array is the same, the string(array) has no same words.

```
function func($str) {
    $arr = explode( ' ', $str );
    return count(array_unique( $arr )) === count( $arr );
}

echo func( "car apple computer car" );
echo func( "car apple computer" );
```

Doc: [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: Can anyone explain, why this gets two downvotes?

Comment: @Philipp Not the down-voter but I'm assuming it is because it is an answer to a poor question and that is sometimes frowned upon.

Comment: Wow 3 downvotes ha? Haha

Comment: @Eddie now I see that this is not correct
for  string  = "car apple cars"

Comment: @JirkaLuňák What do you mean? carS and car are the same?

Comment: @Eddie sorry my mistake

Comment: Happy to help @JirkaLuňák :)

Comment: @Eddie Thank you Have a nice time :)

Answer (score -1):

Split the sentence by spaces using `explode()`. Count the elements, then use `array_unique()`. The count of elements will drop if there are duplicates.

```
<?php

function hasSameWords($string) {

    $array = explode(' ', $string);
    $count = count($array);
    $unique = array_unique($array);
    $uniqueCount = count($unique);

    return $uniqueCount < $count;
}


$string = "car apple computer car";
$string2 = "car apple computer";

echo hasSameWords($string) ? 'true' : 'false';
echo hasSameWords($string2) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Try it here : https://3v4l.org/8iidN